# disable scrolling in an iframe

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to disable scrolling all together in an iframe?

I have an iframe where the content exceeds the iframe dimensions, setting scrolling=no only removes the scrollbars but doesn't disable scrolling.

I don't have control over the head of the iframe-html, so I can't style my way out it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the css overflow property? the hidden value may help do what you want. Why do you want to hide this? Most times I see this it is related to bad SEO or trying to hide other info from the user.

Comment: My iframe has a body with a set width, the content that exceeds the iframe is blank - but when a user scrubs the area with the mouse the content moves.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can trap the keys normally used for scrolling with javascript and stop their normal behavior?