# HTML iframe - disable scroll

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have following iframe in my site:

```
<iframe src="<<URL>>" height="800" width="800" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms" scrolling="no" style="overflow: hidden"></iframe>
```

And it has scrolling bars.
How to get rid of them?

Comment: Herman - I think `scrolling="no"` should work.Its work for me. is it in HTML5 ?

Comment: @Yagnesh I have post you sample of my iframe and it is not working.

Comment: I have tried with your code and it working fine without scroll. Pls check if iframe is under any div.

Comment: Perhaps the <body> inside the iframe is adding the scrollbars, and not the <iframe>?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not believe it's possible in fully-conforming HTML5 with just HTML and CSS properties. Fortunately however, most browsers do still support the `scrolling` property (which was removed from the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element)).

`overflow` isn't a solution for HTML5 as the only modern browser which **wrongly** supports this is Firefox.

A current solution would be to combine the two:

```html
<iframe src="" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

```css
iframe {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

But this could be rendered obsolete as browsers update. You may want to check this for a JavaScript solution: http://www.christersvensson.com/html-tool/iframe.htm

**Edit:** I've checked and `scrolling="no"` will work in IE10, Chrome 25 and Opera 12.12.

Comment: The <iframe> scrolling attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead. Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp

Comment: @LinusAn this is what the first line of my answer states. The problem is though that browsers can't really just drop it altogether as it would break HTML4 websites, so the `scrolling` attribute is still a viable, albeit invalid option.

Comment: This is correct, but in Chrome this breaks the scrollIntoView on elements within the iframe.
See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137214

Comment: @Linus - unfortunately, that shouldn't work, and any browsers in which it does work are non-conformant : overflow should not be applied to replaced elements like buttons, form elements and iframes.

Comment: This cuts out content.

Comment: @DaniSpringer have you provided an adequate size for the `iframe`?

Comment: I believe so. How can I check?

Comment: @DaniSpringer This solution is SUPPOSED to cut out content. Loading an iframe without the ability to scroll does not automatically resize the entire child page to fit into the designated iframe dimensions.

Comment: @Nate how can I do just that? Thanks for getting back.

Comment: @DaniSpringer If what you're asking is to show an iframe shrunk down to a thumbnail, then I suggest you use CSS3 transform (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp). Working example: http://codepen.io/progidy/pen/pgqzgM

Comment: @Nate no. Force page height to height of frame. No scrolling. No cut off.

Comment: @DaniSpringer As far as I see it, you have 3 choices for an iframe: 1) show iframe at 100% zoom, but overflow can scroll; 2) show iframe at 100% zoom but prevent scroll; 3) show iframe zoomed to fit entirely in frame. You have turned down all 3. Can you describe what you are trying to do? If you force page height to frame with no scrolling, you must cut off. If no cut off and no zoom out, then _____.

Comment: @Nate sorry if I was unclear. I'd like the page to stretch so the frame fits. No scroll. No cut.

Answer (score 23):

I solved the same issue with this css:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Comment: It seems to block the physical attempt to scroll, just not the visual scrollbars...

Comment: This will prevent any mouse events firing on the iframe, including scrolling. Way too broad to be a robust solution

Comment: I had to use this to prevent scrolling in an iframe that is embedded in a `foreignobject` in a SVG image (just `overflow: hidden` didn't work)

Comment: This does not stop scrolling via the mouse scroll wheel (in Chromium).
Also I believe the OP wants to actually hide the scroll bars; you should move your answer over to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712034/ as I believe that this partially solves that question.

Comment: Thanks, at least the iframe scrolling is disabled.

Comment: If we disable events then it can create other issues which is not good solution

Comment: I came here by finding GoFundMe implemented this for their 'Fundraiser Preview" iframe. **Ridiculous**. Good thing it was easy for me to overcome it. Terrible UX experience.

Answer (score 14):

It seems to work using

```
html, body { overflow: hidden; }
```

**inside** the IFrame

edit: 
Of course this is only working, if you have access to the Iframe's content (which I have in my case)

Comment: When using an iframe though, you usually can't access what's in it, because it's often for including content on another domain.

Answer (score 2):

Set all the content to:

```
#yourContent{
 width:100%;
height:100%;  // in you csss
}
```

The thing is that the iframe scroll is set by the content NOT by the iframe by itself.

set the content to 100% in the interior with CSS and the desired for the iframe in HTML

Answer (score 1):

Since the *"overflow: hidden;"* property does not properly work on the iFrame itself, but seems to give results when applied to the body of the page *inside* the iFrame, I tried this :

```
iframe body { overflow:hidden; }
```

Which surprisingly **did** work with Firefox, removing those annoying scrollbars.

In Safari though, a weird 2-pixels-wide transparent line has appeared on the right side of the iframe, between its contents and its border. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

I tried scrolling="no" in my current browser (Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and that didn't work.  However, scroll="no" did work.  Might be worth trying

```
<iframe src="<<URL>>" height="800" width="800" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms" scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden"></iframe>
```

Comment: actually, digging into this a bit further, I think the cause was just me changing the height="" to be longer than the actual iFrame I am trying to load.  So making the height long enough to make scrolling nonsensical actually made the scroll bar go away for me.  I am trying to display the entire page though, which might be different from what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an actual answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks JDV! I'm new to StackOverflow so I tried to comment but didn't have enough reputation points or whatever it's called. So I agree, it should have been a comment. Appreciate your guidance!

Comment: There are ways you can contribute until you get the necessary rep. https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<style>
*{overflow:hidden!important;}
html{overflow:scroll!important;}
</style>
```

Note: if you need scrollbar in any other element, also add css `{overflow:scroll!important;}` to that element

Answer (score -1):

Just add an iframe styled like either option below. I hope this solves the problem.

1st option:

```
<iframe src="https://www.skyhub.ca/featured-listing" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;" onload="this.style.position='static'; this.style.visibility='visible';" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="400px" width="1200px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

2nd option:

```
<iframe src="https://www.skyhub.ca/featured-listing" style="display: none;" onload="this.style.display='block';" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="400px" width="1200px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this styles..for your iframe tag..

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
```

Comment: `Overflow` doesn't work on HTML5 iFrames. The only browser which *wrongly* supports this is Firefox.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Actually he didnt specified it is html5, thats why we used overflow

Answer (score -2):

For this frame:

```
    <iframe src="" name="" id=""></iframe>
```

I tried this on my css code:

```
    iframe#put the value of id here::-webkit-scrollbar {
         display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

below html5 versions

```
iframe {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

In html5

```
<iframe seamless="seamless"  ....>


iframe[seamless]{

   overflow: hidden;
}
```

**but not supported correctly yet**

Comment: As per [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-seamless) and [this](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/331), the `seamless` attribute has been removed from the spec.