# Disable touch on an iframe but keep clicking ability

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe which is blocking the layer below and dose not let it to scroll by touch in phone and tablet devices. Is there any way to disable the touch only on the iframe using it's class name or the class name of the div that is holding it?

Comment: what do you mean touch? or do you mean scroll -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `pointer-events` to disable any touch events on the element:

```
iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

JSFiddle example:

**http://jsfiddle.net/eyync6mp/2/**

Comment: As I mentioned in the title, "I need to keep the clicking ability" so I cannot use pointer-event

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I was confused because you said "Is there any way to disable the touch only on the iframe..."