# How can I force an iframe to resize to fit the embedded document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe that has quite a bit of white space tacked onto the end of visible elements.  In fact, I know that the iframe is loading the size of all my elements including hidden elements.  These elements were meant to be hidden until some knockout questions are answered, at which point the iframe should resize accordingly.

The other battle I am fighting with this is the fact that I am also having to deal with two scroll bars, one for the iframe, and of course the web page scroll bar.  This is just very tacky and not very user friendly.

This is a problem I inherited, so I am hoping for a solution involving the iframe.  I am also willing to explore other solutions as maybe this is not the most appropriate as it is.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might update the height of the `<iframe>` from the framed page using JavaScript after a new element is shown.

```
function resizeParent() {
    if (!window.parent) return;

    var height = $(document).height();
    $(window.parent.document).find('iframe').height(height);
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/ewey6f1v/)

#### [Source of framed page](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/yqykk1yt/)

*Note, this will only work if both pages are loaded from the same domain.*

Comment: This seems to work for when the page loads, and it may be my client side skills still trying to catch up, but I cannot seem to update the height when I add additional elements, they seem to be hidden at the bottom as the iframe grows.  I am assuming that I am not updating the parent height respectively?

Comment: @jimfromthegym-JimMackin Step 1: Open the framed page in the directly see if everything is visible on the page. Step 2: Make sure you call `resizeParent()` after a knockout question is anwsered. For reference see how it works in the jsfiddles, note than I'm calling `resizeParent()` on button click.

Answer (score 5):

To get rid of scroll bars, try adding `scrolling="no"` to the iframe.
[HTML iframe - disable scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll)

Comment: Simply disabling scrolling doesn't make the iframe resize.

Answer (score 1):

Use both the inline style attribute `style="overflow:hidden;"` as well as the attribute `scrolling="no"`. `overflow:hidden` is the proper HTML5 counterpart, so it's best to mix both.

**Edit:** In fact, if it is suited for your case, try using the iframe `seamless` boolean attribute. It practically makes the iframe styled as if it's part of the containing document, including no borders or scrollbars. I recommend it because it's like a one-stop for what you need to accomplish, and it does the work for you. You can try a combination of all the three attributes I recommended for ideal browser compatibility.

Comment: `seamless` would work great, except that almost no browser is supporting it (yet). source: http://caniuse.com/seamless