# iFrame Disable scrolling all together

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need to have an iFrame with design mode however I need the ability to move at all disabled. I added scrolling="no" to the iFrame but you can still navigate using the arrow keys when you have written to the bottom. How can I stop this so it is set in stone and isnt going anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a CSS style like this

```html
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried this .We may be thinking differently, what div or element should this go on?

Comment: You would apply it to the actual iFrame, reference this article for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll