# Don't propagate mouse wheel scrolling to IFRAME and its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scroll

On my page I have `iframe` that contains some `div`s with scrollbars:
http://jsfiddle.net/gdx6L940/

The `iframe`'s content is from another domain, so I do not have access to its content via DOM.

How can I block mouse-wheel scrolling of the `iframe` and its content? What I want to achieve is that mouse-wheel scroll will always scroll the parent page, even if the cursor is over the `iframe`.

**EDIT**

I made a little bit more real-world example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gdx6L940/2/

I want to prevent the inner `iframe`'s divs (facebok feed) from scrolling with mouse wheel.

**EDIT**

To make sure: I do not want to disable scrollbars on IFRAME element nor block all events completely. I would like to block only mouse-scrolls, but preserving the ability to click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML iframe - disable scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll)

Comment: No, that's not the case.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you can simply set another div element over the existing one and then put the transparency of that at 100%. that may not be the correct way of achieving your goal but it should work. I'll test it and make edits if necessary

Comment: But won't this block also other events like clicks?

Comment: yes it would this option would be most useful if you were simply trying to let them view a portion of another page, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to block only scrolls, preserving the ability to click.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got to do **partially** what you want

use the code to prevent the browser from scrolling inside the div (that is inside you iframe)

```
window.addWheelListener(div_el, function(e) {
  console.log(e.deltaY);
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

the working example and `addWheelListener` code is in my [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/thiagoh/xspxoh04/)

Comment: will this work if I do not have the access to iframe's content? (another domain)

Comment: hmm, I haven't tested this scenario but I don't think so.. Could you please try and tell us?

Comment: as I imagined.. Thank you @Gacek

Answer (score 1):

You can catch mousewheel event

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.onmousewheel=function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: will this work if I do not have the access to iframe's content? (another domain)

Comment: For sure not : if you can't modify iframe content it won't work

Comment: We're not here to talk about product behavior, but I don't think avoid a user to scroll a div where he can see a scrollbar is a real-world solution.

Comment: Well, he can always click or drag the scrollbars. That's the point.

Answer (score 0):

Just did some more research and it would appear that what you are trying to do is just not possible to do the way you want to do it.

also possible duplicate of 
[HTML iframe - disable scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll)