# Disable scrolling in an iframe from an external domain (HTML)

Tags: html, css, iframe

I made an iframe at [Rubiks3x3.com](http://rubiks3x3.com/algorithm/edit.html) to show users of my page algrithms. You get the following code:

```html
<iframe height="270" width="300px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="https://rubiks3x3.com/algorithm/"></iframe>
```

There is the 'scrolling attribute. My Validator says it is obsolete and gives me a link where it says I should add the attribute "overflow" to the root element of the containing document, but I can't find a way to do so because I can't find a way to contact elements inside the document embedded. Is CSS really the right way to do something like that? If yes how; and if no what else can I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML iframe - disable scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll)

Comment: `overflow:hidden` is the CSS way

Comment: Yeah, I know, but my problem is not the way how to write it but the way to contact the "root element" of the embedded element. I can write `overflow: hidden` whereever I want but it doesn't have any effect to the iframe...