# Disable scroll within the iframe but still allow the scroll in the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Hi I have an iframe in my web page. I want the scroll within the iframe to be disabled but if I scroll in iframe my web page should scroll and not the content in iFrame.

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll

Answer (score 0):

You should change your iframe css to: `overflow: hidden;`