# how to make a iframe responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do i make this code work without the scrollbar. and still show all the contents coming from the link in the iframe.

```
   <html>
      <head>
        <title>How to make Iframe Responsive</title>
          </head>
             <body>
                <div style="padding-bottom:56.25%; position:relative; display:block; width: 100%">
              <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.inflatableoffice.com/quotes/quoteme.php name=Starwalk+of+Dallas%2C+LLC" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="position:absolute; top:0; left: 0"></iframe>
             </div>
           </body>
      </html>
```

I want it to display without the sidebars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML iframe - disable scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

Add `scrolling="no"` attribute to the iframe tag.

```
<iframe scrolling="no" ...></iframe>
```

Comment: This removes the scroll but some of the contents are lost in the body

Comment: Right. I don't understand what else you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

On your wrapper `div`, add the property `overflow:hidden;`. This will of course hide vertical and horizontal overflow though. You can control either one with either `overflow-x:hidden;` or `overflow-y:hidden;`. Try this:

```
   <html>
      <head>
        <title>How to make Iframe Responsive</title>
          </head>
             <body>
                <div style="overflow:hidden; padding-bottom:56.25%; position:relative; display:block; width: 100%">
              <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.inflatableoffice.com/quotes/quoteme.php name=Starwalk+of+Dallas%2C+LLC" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="position:absolute; top:0; left: 0"></iframe>
             </div>
           </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Removes the scroll but the contents in the bottom are gone

Comment: @OnomeMineAdams as expected overflow would do. That's why I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @OnomeMineAdams however, if the OP has a specific size for the iframe and wrapper set in CSS, then this can work as a benefit in certain cases. I'm not sure if all browsers support the `scrollbar` attribute, so this approach would work better for all browsers as far as I can tell.