# Is there a CSS property to hide a iframe's scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need to hide a **iframe's** scrollbar with **CSS**, but the **HTML** attribute `scroll="no"` is the only thing that works. I don't want to use it because it is not supported with **HTML5**. This is my **CSS**:

```css
iframe {
    width: 600px;
    height: 490px;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That didn't help.
I have tried [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org), but it only showed the non-supported attribute. Do I need to use **JavaScript**?

By the way, what does the non-supported attribute `seamless="seamless"` mean?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to disable iframe scrolling in HTML5 with just HTML and CSS.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll

Comment: is the iframed site your own site?

Comment: @doğukan Yes it is

Comment: Thanks @AMR. I wish there was.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with **JavaScript** @AMR?