# How to remove scrolling iframe. Tried known solutions

Tags: css, iframe, scrollbar, overflow

Im trying to remove the scrollbar over at https://cardmart.com.au. If you click on "contact" it loads a form within an iframe and I cant for the life of me figure out how to remove that scroll bar.

I looked at solutions in this thread - [HTML iframe - disable scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494568/html-iframe-disable-scroll)

But its not working on my situation or I am implementing it wrong.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the scroll isn't on the `iframe`, it is on the `body` of the `iframe`. I was playing around with the Google Developer tools, and found that if you add `overflow: hidden;` to your `iframe`, it doesn't work. You'll have to go to the page that is being represented in the `iframe` and add this `style` to the `body` of that page:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Other code */
}
```

Comment: Works a treat. Cheers for that. Had to add in the "Custom Javascript & CSS" area of the Powr.io form that im pulling from.